# Matlab to C or C++

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I am working on an image processing project using Matlab. We should run our program (intended to be an application) on a cell phone.We were then asked to convert our code into C or C++ language so we get a feel of how long it would take for execution and then choose a platform. So far we didn't figure out how to do this conversion.. Any ideas of what to do to convert Matlab to C or C++??

Comment: This question is unanswerable. The only way to do this is to rewrite your _specific_ algorithms in C or C++.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi No, it is certainly answerable. You can automatically convert some Matlab programs into C or C++ using [Matlab Coder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5913631/975097).

Comment: Matlab Coder does not do a good job. I keep getting error when trying to run the c code

Answer (score 15):

The first thing you need to realise is that porting code from one language to another (especially languages as different as Matlab and C++) is generally non-trivial and time-consuming. You need to know both languages well, and *you need to have similar facilities available in both*. In the case of Matlab and C++, Matlab gives you a lot of stuff that you just won't have available in C++ without using libraries. So the first thing to do is identify which libraries you're going to need to use in C++. (You can write some of the stuff yourself, but you'll be there a long time if you write *all* of it yourself.)

If you're doing image processing, I highly recommend looking into something like ITK at http://www.itk.org -- I've written my image processing software twice in C++, once without ITK (coding everything myself) and once with, and the version that used ITK was finished faster, performed better and was ten times more fun to work on. FWIW.

Comment: Incidentally, ITK might look as if it's just for segmentation and registration, but it's actually pretty good for general image processing as well.

Answer (score 12):

Matlab can gererate C code for you.

See:
http://www.mathworks.com/products/featured/embeddedmatlab/

The generated code does however depend on matlab libraries. So you probably can't use it for a cell phone. But it might save you some time anyways.

Comment: Follow the link here for alphabetical or categorical lists 
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/eml/ug/bsud5f4.html

Answer (score 8):

I also used the [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) to convert some functions consisting of a few hundred lines of MATLAB into C. This included using MATLAB's eigenvalue solver and matrix inversion functions.

Although Coder was able to produce C code (which theoretically was identical), it was very convoluted, bloated, impossible to decipher, and appeared to be extremely inefficient. It literally created about 10x as many lines of code as it should have needed. I ended up converting it all by hand so that I would actually be able to comprehend the C code later and make further changes/updates. This task however, can be very tedious/dangerous, as the array indexing in Matlab is 1-based and in C it's 0-based. You're likely to add bugs into the code, as I experienced. you'll also have to convert any vector/matrix arithmetic into loops that handle scalars (or use some type of C matrix algebra package)

Answer (score 5):

The MathWorks provides a product called [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) that claims to generate "readable and portable C and C++ code from MATLAB® code". I haven't tried it myself, so I can't comment on how well it accomplishes these goals.

With regard to the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/), [this list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html#bsl0arh-1) (presumably for R2016b) shows which functions have been enabled for code generation and any limitations they may have.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has a tool called "Matlab Coder" which can convert your matlab file to C code or mex file. My code is relatively simple so it works fine. Speed up gain is about 10 times faster. This saves me time coding a few hundreds lines. Hope it's helpful for you too

[Quick Start Guide for MATLAB Coder Confirmation](https://www.mathworks.com.au/programs/products/download_matlab-coder_conf.html?confirmation_page&wfsid=5403284)

The links describe the process of converting your code in 3 major steps:

- First you need to make a few simplifications in your present code so that it would be simple enough for the Coder to translate.
- Second, you will use the tool to generate a mex file and test if everything is actually working.
- Finally you would change some setting and generate the C code. In my case, the C code has about 700 lines including all the original matlab code (about 150 lines) as comments. I think it's quite readable and could be improve upon. However, I already get a 10 times speed up gain from the mex file anyway. So this is definitely a good thing.

We can't not be sure that this will work in all case but it's definitely worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I remember there is a tool to export m-files as c(++)-files. But I could never get that running. You need to add some obscure MATLAB-headers in the c/c++code, ... And I think it is also not recommended.

If you have running MATLAB-code, it shouldn't take too much effort to do the conversion "by hand". I have been working on several project where MATLAB was used and it was never consider to use any tools to convert the code to C/C++. It was always done "by hand".

I believe to have been the only one who ever investigate into using a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not straight conversion from matlab to c/c++ You will need to understand the language and the differences between matlab and c/c++ and then start coding it in c/c++. **Code a little test a little until it works.**