# MATLAB to C code conversion

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matlab to C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166755/matlab-to-c-or-c)

is there any software to convert MATLAB code to c....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB is able to compile your .m files to binary files if you just want them to run faster:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html

Comment: you are being deceived by the term "compiler" as it is used by Mathworks. It is not a compiler but a "packager" like MATLAB p-code and you still need interpreter (MATLAB Common Runtime) and the code does not run faster - actually it runs slower.

Comment: You are mistaken - I have used Matlab extensively for 4.5 years during my PhD research and it is possible to compile Matlab code into binary.

Comment: OK, to be precise it was possible with MATLAB 6, the things changed when MATLAB 7 came out in 2004

Comment: The matlab compiler only allows you to make your scripts distributable. There are no speed gains to be had in the newer versions of matlab.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Embedded Matlab. Works well but only allows use of a subset of matlab functions.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/featured/embeddedmatlab/

It is fine for converting your algorithms into C without having to worry about the possibility of errors being introduced in hand conversion. you will need a license for rtw.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/rtw/

Answer (score 1):

If C++ is acceptable, you could try a library such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html), which provides C++ versions of many MATLAB functions. This allows for a relatively easy conversion of many functions.